# ValidationError when using pydantic Field

Tags: fastapi, pydantic

I run these codes by defining two classes, Blackboard and Table, based on BaseModel. The I defined another class which takes two attributes: bloackboard, defined to be a Blackboard; tables, defined to be a list of Table class objects.

```
from typing import List
from pydantic import BaseModel, Field


class Blackboard(BaseModel):
    size = 4000
    color: str = Field(..., alias='yanse',
                       description='the color of the blackboard, you can choose green or black.')


class Table(BaseModel):
    position: str


class ClassRoom(BaseModel):
    blackboard: Blackboard
    tables: List[Table]


m = ClassRoom(
    blackboard={'color': 'green'},
    tables=[{'position': 'first row, left 1'}, {'position': 'first row, left 2'}]
)
```

I got an error :

```
File "pydantic\main.py", line 342, in pydantic.main.BaseModel.__init__
pydantic.error_wrappers.ValidationError: 1 validation error for ClassRoom
blackboard -> yanse
  field required (type=value_error.missing)
```

I want to know how could I correctly use Field class.

Thanks

I expect to have no error.

Comment: You gave it an alias, so you should use the alias.

Comment: Thank you. After using the alias, the problem is solved!

Answer (score 2):

You are using an alias for the color field in your schema and filling your data with python dictionaries.

in this case, you should replace:

```
blackboard={'color': 'green'}
```

with:

```
blackboard={'yanse': 'green'}
```

The color field is used when you have a python schema object, not in dictionaries.

Answer (score 0):

In case you wanted to populate your `Blackboard` model using `color`, you can activate `allow_population_by_field_name` option in the `Blackboard` config options as follow:

```
class Blackboard(BaseModel):
    size = 4000
    color: str = Field(..., alias='yanse',
                       description='the color of the blackboard,
                        you can choose green or black.')

    class Config:
          allow_population_by_field_name = True
```